# Is it true that every finite dimensional matrix is a bounded linear operator?

Tags: functional-analysis

Is it true that every finite dimensional matrix is a bounded linear operator? 
How to calculate its norm then? Is it related to singular value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, every operator between finite dimensional vector spaces (which includes all finite matrices) is bounded. If the norm taken on the underlying spaces $\Bbb R^n$ and $\Bbb R^m$ is the usual Euclidean norm, then the induced operator norm on the matrix will be precisely the largest singular value.

In particular, we have
$$
\left(\sup_{\|x\|=1} \|Ax\|\right)^2=
\sup_{\|x\|=1} (Ax)^T(Ax)=
\sup_{\|x\|=1} x^T(A^TA)x
$$
and by the Rayleigh Ritz theorem, this coincides with $\sigma_1^2$.

Comment: Can you explain how Euclidean norm and svd are related?

Comment: I'll edit my answer if I get the chance, but in a few words: the Rayleigh-Ritz theorem.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that every linear operator on a finite dimensional space is bounded. This is related to the fact that all norms on a finite dimensional space are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are various norms the matrix could have. For example $$\Vert A \Vert_2 = \bigg(\sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n |a_{ij}|^2 \bigg)^{-\frac{1}{2}},$$

and it is clear that as we are summing up finite quantities the total will simply be a finite number and hence bounded.